# Proving Orthogonality in $RL^2$

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality

I am trying to prove that the functions $g_n(x) = z^n$ , $g_n \in \mathbb{RL^2}$ are orthogonal. However, I am struggling with the fact that they are only rational and analytic on the unit circle rather than the disk. I know I need to compute the integral:

$\int_{|z|=1} \bar{z}^n z^m \frac{dz}{z} = \int_{|z|=1} \bar{z}^n z^{m-1}dz$

but can't seem to get where I want to go with it.
Any help- even a nudge in the right direction- would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Bbb {RL}^2$?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware that this was non-standard notation. It is the set of functions that are rational and analytic on |z|=1.

Comment: Since $\bar{z} = z^{-1}$ on the unit circle, your integral is $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} z^{m-n} \frac{dz}{z}$. You could finish the calculation using the Cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. In the unit circle, $\bar{z} = z^{-1}$. Thus $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \bar{z}^n z^m \frac{dz}{z} = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{z^{m-n}\, dz}{z}$$ Use the Cauchy integral formula to complete the argument.